# Is This Mathematical Induction?

Tags: soft-question, induction

Mathematical induction Follows Thus:

$1.$ The basis (base case): prove that the statement holds for the first natural number $n$. Usually, $n = 0$ or $n = 1$.

$2.$ The inductive step: prove that, if the statement holds for some natural number $n$, then the statement holds for $n + 1$.

For example, when $F_{n}$ is the $n$th Fibonacci Number, it is known that $${ { F }_{ 1 } }^{ 2 }+{ { F }_{ 2 } }^{ 2 }+\dots+{ { F }_{ n } }^{ 2 }=F_nF_{n+1}$$

$1$. When $n=1$, ${ { F }_{ 1 } }^{ 2 }=1=F_1F_{2}$

$2$. Assume that the statement is true for $n-1$. Then ${ { F }_{ 1 } }^{ 2 }+{ { F }_{ 2 } }^{ 2 }+\dots+{ { F }_{ n } }^{ 2 }=F_nF_{n-1}+{ { F }_{ n } }^{ 2 }=F_nF_{n+1}$.

However, what if we show that if the statement is not true for $n+1$, then it is not true for $n$? For example, assume ${ { F }_{ 1 } }^{ 2 }+{ { F }_{ 2 } }^{ 2 }+\dots+{ { F }_{ n } }^{ 2 }\neq F_nF_{n+1}$.

Substracting ${ { F }_{ n } }^{ 2 }$ on both sides gives us that ${ { F }_{ 1 } }^{ 2 }+{ { F }_{ 2 } }^{ 2 }+\dots+{ { F }_{ n-1 } }^{ 2 }\neq F_nF_{n-1}$.

Keep substracting ${ { F }_{ i } }^{ 2 }$, and this gives us that ${ { F }_{ 1 } }^{ 2 } \neq F_1F_{2}$. A contradiction.

It appeared to me that this was not induction, rather a proof by contradiction. Is this or is this not mathematical induction? Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is an inductive proof.  When you have an inductive proof you require two "subproofs" a proof for the base step and a proof for the inductive step.  In this case your proof for the inductive step is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: How so? There does not appear to be two subproofs, in my opinion. Is the fact that $F_{1}^2 \neq F_{1}F_{2}$  the base step then? or is it the inductive step?